# How to call a procedure/function in a snowflake SQL query dynamically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Theres very litte on this topic so far on StackOverflow and nothing has helped me with this issue. I've been trying to call a function inside a simple snowflake select query, pasted bellow. The error I keep getting is: "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated". I've also tried using stored procedures but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
SELECT  CUST.CUSTID , GET_ORD_COUNT(CUST.CUSTID , 0,10)
FROM SALES.CUSTOMERS AS CUST
```

The function I am trying to use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_ORD_COUNT(CUSTID INT, COUNT_FROM INT, COUNT_TO INT)
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*)
from(
SELECT  ORD1.ORDERID , ORD1.CUSTID, ORD1.ORDERDATE, MIN(ORD2.ORDERDATE) AS ORDERDATE2, DATEDIFF("D", ORD1.ORDERDATE , MIN(ORD2.ORDERDATE)) AS DaysDiff
FROM    SALES.ORDERS ORD1
LEFT JOIN SALES.ORDERS ORD2 ON ORD1.CUSTID = ORD2.CUSTID AND ORD2.ORDERDATE > ORD1.ORDERDATE
GROUP BY ORD1.ORDERID, ORD1.CUSTID , ORD1.ORDERDATE
HAVING DAYSDIFF IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ORD1.CUSTID, ORD1.ORDERDATE 
) AS SALES_COUNT 
WHERE SALES_COUNT.DAYSDIFF <= COUNT_TO AND SALES_COUNT.DAYSDIFF >= COUNT_FROM AND SALES_COUNT.CUSTID = CUSTID
GROUP BY SALES_COUNT.CUSTID
$$;
```

The function works fine with hard coded values but that has no use for me.

Comment: "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated" mean you are doing a correlated subquery, which snowflake has very poor support for. The normal solution is to but the full set of answers and merge join to that.

Comment: sometimes people want to use a stored procedure to "hide the complexity of sales_count" or to "keep it consistent" they why to allow this is to make that CTE a  Table Function and Join with it much like how I have joined the CTE.

Comment: If you are joining to the same sub-querry many times, you will be much better performance by computing the inner select a single time, and joining to the result set as you need. Snowflake is imho for doing complex queries that don't run elsewhere, so why would you run them the worst way, just to "hide" some complexity that is not that complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So change from a procedure to a CTE, we move the inside of the function which is variable independent into a CTE `sales_count` then we have a second CTE `cust_data` purely for demonstrative purposes, as if these values are not changing the should be moved into the "function" which implies they are open to change, thus allowing them to be changed, when this join the two datasets using the logic that was present in the outer later of the function.

```
WITH sales_count AS (
    SELECT  ord1.orderid 
        ,ord1.custid
        ,ord1.orderdate
        ,MIN(ord2.orderdate) AS orderdate2
        ,DATEDIFF("D", ord1.orderdate , MIN(ord2.orderdate)) AS daysdiff
    FROM sales.orders AS ord1
    LEFT JOIN sales.orders AS ord2 
        ON ord1.custid = ord2.custid AND ord2.orderdate > ord1.orderdate
    GROUP BY ord1.orderid, ord1.custid, ord1.orderdate
    HAVING daysdiff IS NOT NULL
), cust_data AS (
    SELECT cust.custid
        ,0 AS count_from
        ,10 AS count_to
    FROM sales.customers AS cust
)
SELECT c.custid
    ,c.count_from
    ,c.count_to
    ,count(*) AS count
FROM cust_data AS c
JOIN sales_count AS s 
    ON s.custid = c.custid AND s.daysdiff <= c.count_to AND s.daysdiff >= c.count_from 
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

The CTE `sales_count` can have `ord1.orderid` removed from the select as it's not used in the join and because it's explicitly named in the order by it provides value (in this present question), thus that could be:

```
WITH sales_count AS (
    SELECT  ord1.custid
        ,ord1.orderdate
        ,MIN(ord2.orderdate) AS orderdate2
        ,DATEDIFF("D", ord1.orderdate , MIN(ord2.orderdate)) AS daysdiff
    FROM sales.orders AS ord1
    LEFT JOIN sales.orders AS ord2 
        ON ord1.custid = ord2.custid AND ord2.orderdate > ord1.orderdate
    GROUP BY ord1.orderid, ord1.custid, ord1.orderdate
    HAVING daysdiff IS NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, just like you assumed in your other comment I am trying to hide and simplify as much of the code as possible. Besides that I am trying to reuse the code for different DateDiff ranges (in this case its from 0 to 10 days). Is there a way I could call the query like: `SELECT  CUST.CUSTID , GET_ORD_COUNT(CUST.CUSTID , 0,10),GET_ORD_COUNT(CUST.CUSTID , 11,50)`. So I can get all these different date ranges in a single query?

Comment: you cannot use a function in the select as that is a correlated subquery. You can join to a TABLE function multiple times. Trying to hide complexity is not the game to play in snowflake.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time!